# My MySQL root user is gone, how do I recover it?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, root, reinstall

I was trying to move the MySQL tables so them were in another folder, so I messed out the plugins table or something like that and I ended up reinstalling the whole thing.

I did `sudo aptitude purge mysql-server` then I removed the MySQL data `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/mysql` and also I removed the data from the other directory I was trying to move the tables.

After reinstallation I supposed I would be able to login using `mysql -u root` but it said the user was wrong. I tried with the old password and the same thing. Then I searched for a way to reset the root password.

So I did `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` then I logged in `mysql -u root` succefully adn then I tried `UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('new-password') where User='root';` with no luck, `0 rows affected`. Then I did `SELECT * FROM User` and all I got was `debian-sys-maint`, nothing more, no root or any other user.

Any little help will be appreciated =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the users you need. There may no `root@localhost` per default.

You could always connect via `mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`

Create your new root user with:
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR NEW PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION`

Comment: But I have to add the permissions manually

Comment: added how you could recreate the root user

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only removed /var/lib/mysql/mysql , the reinstall wouldn't have created the default dbs since the data dir (/var/lib/mysql) still exist. Rename the data dir and try a reinstall once again. You can restore the dbs from the backup once you are set with the root account.

-$

Comment: `aptitude purge` should have been enough